# JMESPath Path Where Key Might Not Exist

Tags: python, json, jmespath

I have a weird JSON construct (I cannot provide the actual data for security reasons, but I can provide the structure, which is all that really matters).

Given the following structure:

```
[
  {
    "a": {
      "b": {
        "c": "d"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "b": {
      "c": "d"
    }
  },
]
```

I need to have a way to always get to `c` without knowing if the path contains `a` or not. Something like:

```
[].*.b.c.d
```

or

```
[].a?.b.c.d
```

Any ideas?

For reference, I am using the jmespath library for python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the JSON:

```json
[
  {
    "a": {
      "b": {
        "c": "d (of a.b.c)"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "b": {
      "c": "d (of b.c)"
    }
  },
  {
    "z": {
      "b": {
        "c": "d (of z.b.c)"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

You can use a combination of the [or expression](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#or-expressions) (`||`) and the [flatten operator](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#flatten) (`[]`) to achieve what you want.

So the expression:

```
[][*.b || b] [] []
```

On the above JSON would yield:

```yaml
[
  {
    "c": "d (of a.b.c)"
  },
  {
    "c": "d (of b.c)"
  },
  {
    "c": "d (of z.b.c)"
  }
]
```

*Note that we have to use the flatten operator twice because of the structure that, sometimes has two levels and sometimes three.*

---

And if you just want the value of `c`:

```
[][*.b || b] [] [].c
```

Will yield:

```json
[
  "d (of a.b.c)",
  "d (of b.c)",
  "d (of z.b.c)"
]
```

Comment: Ah perfect, have been searching online for days with no success. Thanks!